# MATLAB Using colon operator with cell assignment

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I had the following line of code to set the first column of a cell array to false so it could be used for checkboxes in a uitable:

```
result{:,1} = false;
```

It ran as expected many times, but seemingly randomly threw up this error:

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values
to satisfy the left hand side.
```

I ended up changing the line to:

```
result(:,1) = {false};
```

and it seems to be working as before.

Is there any reason why the first way shouldn't work? Or any reason why it would work for a while and then stop?

Comment: Interesting question about indexing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You original line

```
result{:,1} = false;
```

will work if `result` has one row, but not if it has several rows. So my guess is that *it worked initially because `result` had one row, but stopped working because `result` acquired new rows*.

Why is this so?

If `result` has a single row, the statement `result{:,1} = false;` is the same as `result{1,1} = false;`, that is, "*set the content of the upper left cell of `result` to `false`*", which is fine. However, if `result` has `n` rows, the left-hand side of the statement `result{:,1} = false;` is a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the contents of `n` cells. **You can't assign a single *value* to several cells' *contents***. Matlab does not automatically replicate that value and put it as all those cells' contents.

A solution is to tell Matlab to do that replication using [`deal`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) (which effectively "deals" that value to all left-hand side "receivers"):

```
result{:,1} = deal(false);
```

Of course, this also works if there is a single row.

Another possibility would be to use, as you did,

```
result(:,1) = {false};
```

This means "*make all cells in the first column of `result` equal to a cell containing `false`*". Note the difference with the previous case: now we are **assigning a *cell* to several *cells***. Matlab is happy with that, and automatically replicates the right-hand cell. And again, this also works for a single row as a particular case.